# Issue with @JoinColumn with columns with the same name JpaMapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need some guidance here.
I have the next [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNOVZ.png) (sorry, I can't upload images yet)
In this database, some columns have the same name (idDireccion for example), but in the server side, the foreign key is defined like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXdLG.png).

The problem I'm getting is because Springboot is detecting the columns have the same name, I don´t know if I'm missing something at mapping the database. I know it's about the column names because I change them and it "works" but I rather not to modify the database structure.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4c5C.png) the Java code

I want to clarify something. I don't want the program to create or alter anything in the database. I just want it to be able to insert and edit data.

Sorry if I'm not clear enough, English is not my main language.

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iCita' defined in mx.com.interfaces.iCita defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: idEmpresa in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(Empresa) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

Comment: Could you add the "Empresa" class to check if something is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two mappings that modify the same column `idDireccion`. As it stands, `Planta` is currently mapped with two mappings that modify that column; the direct mapping:

```
@Column(name="idDireccion")
private int idDireccion;
```

and the many-to-one mapping:

```
@ManyToOne(...)
@JoinColumn(name="idDireccion", referencedColumnName="idDireccion")
private Direccion direccion;
```

You probably want to remove the direct mapping.

Also, the error in your question seems unrelated to this problem ("Unable to find column with logical name: idEmpresa..."). Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You were correct with the direct mapping, sorry I missed that :(